# Temperature Conversion- 2's complement - 13bit

Tags: c#, temperature

I am having no end of time trying to convert the following table to something of value in c#.

I have a 2 byte array such as

```
byte[] data = new byte[2];

data [ 0 ] = 0x00;
data [ 1 ] = 0xc9;
```

Does anyhone have a method to convert the below chart to a c# method?

The format is for DS2438 smart battery monitor IC - http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/DS2438.pdf

Note: The bottom 3 bits are always 0 and hence should not be part of the formula and excluded.

The value is multiplied by 0.03125 to produce the final temperature.

So the case in point is 0xc900 which equates to -1760 or -1760 * 0.03125 = -55C

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's just `(float)(sbyte)data[1] + (float)data[0] / 256`.

It doesn't *matter* that it's 13-bit and not 16-bit; because Dallas bit-shifted things to make a nice 8.8 fixed-point representation. If your sensor had more resolution then those low bits would be used, but the math would still be exactly the same.

Comment: Nope - this is incorrect your result produces a temperature of 0.78515625  but it should be -1760 as you then multiple it by 0.03125

Comment: Wrong on two counts; this produces a result of -55.0, and the correct answer is -55.0. I think you've got your bytes in the wrong order.

Comment: try the indexing the other way around perhaps,  which byte is the MSB  data[0] or data[1]

Comment: the way you have written the question, this answer is correct

Comment: You are correct - amazing something so simple has had me stumped for hours.